# How to add Vue project with Vue cli to existing asp.net 4.6 Webforms project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, vue.js, webforms

I tried adding a vue project to a sub-folder in my asp.net 4.6 website project using vue cli.

I would edit the vue app using vs code.

The problems I ran into:

1. I can't use the npm server (`npm run serve`) address since I need to make calls to webapi in asp.net website. First the cors problem, and even after intsalling AspNet cors I have the webforms authentication problem. This is why I run the vue app with vs 2017 from the sub-folder using iis express Like so 'http://localhost:1234/vue-subfolder', which brings me to the
   next problem
2. I would have to run `npm run build` every time I made any change to
   vue app. Running `npm run serve` would not update the vue app
   running on iis express.
3. I'm also using TFS for source control. Each time I would run `npm
   run build' I would get file does not exist errors since js files get deleted and created.

Is there a way create  and  edit the vue app in vs 2017 and have it auto built on saving changes?